# Cannot retrieve file from FutureAccessList if I use getFileAsync instead of Picker.pickSingleFileAsync

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, windows-store-apps

I have an app that retrieves files in two ways: one using a file picker and the other, using the path directly. In both cases, I get the file, add it to the future access list, and save the token in an array. Later in the app, I use the token to retrieve the file using `futureAccessList.getFileAsync`. Now, the 2nd half, i.e. getting back of the file using the token code is identical in both cases, so it must be something in the way I add it to the future access list, because it works when I use the filepicker, but not when I use the path directly.

**Filepicker add code**

```
    // Create the picker object and set options
    var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.viewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.thumbnail;
    openPicker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.musicLibrary;

    // Select MIDI files only
    openPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".mp3"]);

    // Open the picker for the user to pick a file
    openPicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
        if (file) {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Picked file: " + file.name, "sample", "status");

            // Store the file to access again later
            var listToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.futureAccessList.add(file);

            // Save the file mapping. If it exists, overwrite.
            fileMappings[padId] = { padNumber: padId, audioFile: listToken };
        }
        else {
            // The picker was dismissed with no selected file
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Operation cancelled.", "sample", "status");
        }
    });
```

**Direct path add code**

```
    Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary.getFileAsync("filename.mp3").then(function (file) {
        if (file) {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Picked file: " + file.name + ", full path: " + file.path, "sample", "status");

            // Store the file to access again later
            var listToken = Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.futureAccessList.add(file);

            // Save the file mapping. If it exists, overwrite.
            fileMappings['pad0'] = { padNumber: 'pad0', audioFile: listToken };
        }
        else {
            // Could not get access to the file
            WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File unavailable!", "sample", "status");
        }
    });
```

Personally, I feel like this line `(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary.getFileAsync)` doesn't give me read-write access, just read, and that might be what's messing it up. Here is [a related thread on msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9ac695b6-bbce-4c88-95fd-863b895aa763/loading-file-to-player-using-mediaelementsetsource?forum=winappswithcsharp). It's a C#-MediaElement question, but closely related. Any idea what could be wrong here? If it's permissions-related, how can I specify that I need r-w access? I thought specifying capabilities in the appxmanifest was good enough. I can add the file retrieval code here if anyone needs it. Thanks for your time.

[Windows RT app using Javascript. Confirmed 'Music Library' capability is checked.]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it :( but why do you say you need rw access to the file... aren't you just reading it here?

Comment: I don't need read-write access I guess, but I'm guessing that that is what the problem is.

Comment: A storage file, generally does not control read or read write access. it does not represent an open file handle. when you open a random access stream that is where you specify the access you want. There are cases where the storage file does restrict access, when a file is passed to an app as part of the share contract.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. This is a bug in the WinRT API. I work on that part of the system and have filed a bug on this topic.

Comment: link to connect issue / bug report pls? i.e. you say you "filed a bug" but where? Is there definitely a bug? Have MS confirmed this?